# USB(Memory Stick),or any other drivers detection and listing their contents in JAVA

Tags: java, usb, driver, detection, sample

Hey guys i am coding simple USB detection java app and i cant make detect my USB driver or any other drivers, how can i add driver detection? is there any ways or sample java app to detect drivers and its contents? any help would be appreciated

how can i add this following code to my app?

```
public class USBdetection 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{   
String[] letters = new String[]{ "E", "F", "G", "H", "I" ,"J","K", "L","M", "N"};
File[] Externaldrives = new File[letters.length];
boolean[] FoundDrive = new boolean[letters.length];

// init the file objects and the initial drive state

    for ( int i = 0; i < letters.length; ++i )
{
Externaldrives[i] = new File(letters[i]+":/");

FoundDrive[i] = Externaldrives[i].canRead();
}

System.out.println("Waiting for device, Please Wait");

// Search each drive
while(true)
{
for ( int i = 0; i < letters.length; ++i )
{
boolean pluggedIn = Externaldrives[i].canRead();

// if the state has changed output a message
if ( pluggedIn != FoundDrive[i] )
{
if ( pluggedIn )
System.out.println("Drive "+letters[i]+" has been plugged in");

FoundDrive[i] = pluggedIn;
}

}

}
}
}k
```